# Choosing a Model for Inference

Tags: r, regression, inference, ordered-logit

I'm trying to understand what factors contribute to the a certain outcome which is a ordered factor variable. In order to just understand which factor is statistically more significant than the others, I would like to build a model and given that my output variable is an ordered factorial variable - I thought I should go for Ordinal Logistic Regression. Given the tradeoff between interpretability and flexibility of models, in my case since I'm only making inferences and not predictions, should I rather go for a easier model to handle like Generalized Linear Models? It kind of boils down to me choosing the `polr` package in R versus the `glm` one.

Comment: OLR is a form of GLM. In light of that fact, what choice are you talking about? Moreover if your data are ordinal, what other option than OLR do you have in mind?

Comment: I threw the glm function at my data and it seemed to work just like polr - hence the question. I wanted to know if I could go with any other option apart from OLR - but it looks like that's what I have to go with...